# UTF-16 encoding changes the output of the code

Tags: python, character-encoding, export-to-csv

When I try to output data in a CSV using UTF-8 encoding the data comes out delimited but some French characters do not appear.

If I change the encoding type to UTF-16 the French characters appear ok but the data is no longer delimited and appear in a single line.

My code:

```
def data_to_csv(data):
keys = data[0].keys()
with open('data.csv', 'w', newline='', encoding="utf-16") as output_file:
    dict_writer = csv.DictWriter(output_file, keys, delimiter=",")
    dict_writer.writeheader()
    dict_writer.writerows(data)
```

Expected output:
[CSV Expected Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hWRpD.png)

Actual output using UTF-8: [CSV Actual Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O4FXy.png)

Comment: @snakecharmerb You can encode any unicode character as UTF-16 as well. Did you mean UCS-2?

Comment: @snakecharmerb: UTF-8, UTF-16, and UTF-32 are both official encoding of Unicode. Both can handle exact the same code points within Unicode range. -- Steve: check that it is not a problem of your editor/viewer. To me, it seems your editor/console do not understand that the file is UTF-8 (put some accented character near the beginning of the file, or just force it). I assume Latin1?. In the second case, it seems you are reading it as Latin1 ignoring 00.

Comment: @Sören yes I was, my bad.

Comment: A [mojibake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mojibake) case: `'Aurélien € Núñez'.encode( 'utf-8').decode( 'cp1253')` returns `'AurΓ©lien β‚¬ NΓΊΓ±ez'`. In other words: your file is true `utf-8` however open/read as `cp1253`.

Answer (score 0):

Your UTF-8 encoded file is fine. Just whatever program you used to create that screenshot doesn't support UTF-8/isn't configured for it.

Your UTF-16 encoded file is likely fine as well.